# identify last and first measurement during the day

Tags: r, time-series

I am trying to identify 2 points in a time series - the last data point in the morning and the first one in the evening on each day. I marked the relevant points green in the figure below. Note that they are not necessary the highest points - they should be the last one before data go to zero.

I played around with intervals but was not successful ...
Thanks for an input on this!

Michael

Here is a subset of the data where I average per hour ... for one day:

```
structure(list(hour = c(0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 16L, 
17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L), value = c(2.7272895638485, 
2.17238888888889, 1.79964814814815, 1.91384259259259, 2.62237962962963, 
5.37035185185185, 9.16018518518518, 13.5703981481481, 13.8340484814712, 
7.93048148148148, 7.69624074074074, 7.03816666666667, 5.23764814814815, 
4.16410185185185, 4.22922222222222, 3.47449908925319)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -16L))
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please show some of your data using `dput`?

Comment: I added a small dataset with averaged points for each hour ... in principle the questions stays the same :)

Comment: The dataset you added does *not* show the pattern of the picture. There is *no* last data point in the morning and *no* first one in the evening. It would also be nice if the data shows *more than one day*.

Comment: the initial graph hat ~100k datapoints so I decided to average for each hour and to be able to use dput ... the graph is now updated and shows the points I am interested in ... here they are the maximum, but that is not always the case ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `diff` to find the gap in time and get the values before an after the gap like:

```
i <- diff(x$hour) > 1
x[c(i,FALSE) | c(FALSE,i),]
#  hour    value
#8    7 13.57040
#9   16 13.83405
```